# How to send/insert data in more than one Database with PhP / MySql

Tags: php, mysql

I have online shop where customers can order products , since now when order is complete i insert product and user data into database (server1) but now i like to insert same order data into one more database that is hosted in another hosting (server2) , both machines are using php/mysql .

I think to use [PhP cURL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to transfer data from server1 to server2 like this

```
    $curl_handle=curl_init();
     $data = http_build_query($order_data);
     curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_URL,'https://www.server2.com/orders');
     curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
     curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_exec($curl_handle);
    curl_close($curl_handle);
```

My question is: will i do it with cURL or there is something better in MySql that can do it. By the way both servers are shared hosting if is matter

Comment: You could do this directly by using the mysql functions of PHP. If you have wrapper class for all your DB operations you could simply run all the queries twice: One for each DB connection.

Comment: I recommend Herwigs solution but please note that you have to allow mysql access (e.g. port 3306) 1.) in the firewall  of host 2 and 2. in the mysql user table of the server 2.  as usually msql is configured to only accept calls from localhost.

Comment: @AlexanderDobernig ok i will try it but till now i find issue with config mysql because its on shared hosting

Comment: If both sites are on the same hoster and you are not able to change the settings youself - ask your provider if it is possible to access the db2 from host1. 
In Cloud hosting you usually can change everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do something like

```
$host = ['host1','host2'];
$db_name = ['db_name1','db_name2'];
$user = ['user1','user2'];
$pass = ['pass1','pass2'];

for($i=0;$i<count($host);$i++){
   $mysqli = new mysqli($host[$i], $user[$i], $pass[$i], $db_name[$i]);
   or
   $mysqli = mysqli_connect($host[$i], $user[$i], $pass[$i], $db_name[$i]);
   And here the insert code:
   mysqli->query(....);
}
```

You basically initialize the mysqli php built-in function for each database and you can work with each database